# What is the fast way to turn this vector into symmetric matrix?

Tags: r

everyone! Suppose I have a vector of length n(n+1)/2:

```
a = (a_11, a_12, a_22, ...., a_nn)
```

Now I'd like to turn it into a symmetric matrix, mean

[image]

I could assign the value one by one, but I'm wondering if there is some faster to create this matrix? Thanks so much!!

Comment: Providing an actual vector and corresponding expected output instead of the indices would make this a lot easier to answer.

Comment: is it the case that a_12 in the input vector should be inserted into both a_12 and a_21 in the matrix?

Answer (score 3):

You could write a function that does this:

IF you had your vector as `a11,a12,a13..a1n,a22,a23..a2n, a33,..a3n,..ann`
They you could do:

```
vec2mat <- function(x){
  p <- sqrt(1 + 8 * length(x))/ 2 - 0.5
  m <- matrix(0, p, p)
  m[lower.tri(m, diag = TRUE)] <- x
  m[upper.tri(m)] <- (t(m))[upper.tri(m)]
  m
}
```

Now:

```
vec2mat(1:6)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    5
[3,]    3    5    6
vec2mat(1:10)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    5    6    7
[3,]    3    6    8    9
[4,]    4    7    9   10
```

if you had `a11, a12,a22,a31, a32, a33...`

```
vec2mat <- function(x){
  p <- sqrt(1 + 8 * length(x))/ 2 - 0.5
  m <- matrix(0, p, p)
  m[upper.tri(m, diag = TRUE)] <- x
  m[lower.tri(m)] <- t(m)[lower.tri(m)]
  m
}
 vec2mat(1:10)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    4    7
[2,]    2    3    5    8
[3,]    4    5    6    9
[4,]    7    8    9   10
```

Comment: for 1000 elements it crashes... why is that?

Comment: @ManosPapadakis because you can not have 1000 elements. Note that the number must be a triangle number. ie the lower triangle or upper triangle of a square matrix including the diagonal. so the number ie the vector should be of length 990 if it is a square of 44 rows and 44 columns or 1035 if its a square of 45 rows and 45 columns.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
#define n
n <- 2

#Create n(n+1)/2 objects in global environment
#OP already has that
a_11 <- 5
a_12 <- 9
a_22 <- 8

#Create n X n matrix with NA
mat <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = n)
#Get all the individual objects in one vector
vec <- unlist(mget(ls(pattern = 'a_')), use.names = FALSE)
#Replace upper (or lower) triangular elements with it
mat[upper.tri(mat, diag = TRUE)] <- vec
#Copy the elements to other half.
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- mat[upper.tri(mat)]

#      [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    9
#[2,]    9    8
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a sparse matrix like this:

```
a <- 1:6
n <- as.integer(-0.5 + sqrt(0.25 + 2 * length(a)))

library(Matrix)
sparseMatrix(x = a, dims = c(n, n), symmetric = TRUE, 
             i = sequence(1:n), j = rep(1:n, 1:n))
#3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"
#          
#[1,] 1 2 4
#[2,] 2 3 5
#[3,] 4 5 6
```

Use `as.matrix` on the result if you need a dense matrix. If the order of your vector is different than you show (e.g., row-major as some of the other answers assume), you need to adjust calculation of `i` and `j` slightly.

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- 1:25
sq.m <- matrix( a, ncol=sqrt(length(a) ) )

> sq.m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

Obviously this is not a symmetric matrix but if the order of the initial vector would have made one, then it would have succeeded.

If you wanted to coerce a non-square matrix so its upper triangular elements were the same as the lower triangular elements then indexing can be done on both sides of an assignment:

```
 sq.m[ upper.tri(sq.m) ] <- sq.m[lower.tri(sq.m)]
> sq.m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    5   10
[2,]    2    7    4    8   14
[3,]    3    8   13    9   15
[4,]    4    9   14   19   20
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

Comment: OP doesn't have n^2 elements in the input vector. I think the intention is to duplicate certain elements across the diagonal to create one

Comment: His problem presentation suggested to me that he did have n^2 elements. What is your evidence to the contrary.?

Comment: `Suppose I have a vector of length n(n+1)/2:`

Comment: So you have only the lower triangular elements? Ah, now I see. He has only the diagonal and upper triangular elements.

Comment: Does not matter, it is a symmetric matrix. It can be upper triangular or lower.

Comment: @RonakShah You read the problem better than I. You get my vote.

Answer (score 0):

if you have big vectors and speed matters then you can use this function (taken from @Onyambu) that uses Rfast package.

```
vec2mat_rfast <- function(x){
    p <- sqrt(1 + 8 * length(x))/ 2 - 0.5
    m <- matrix(0, p, p)
    m[Rfast::upper_tri(m, diag = TRUE)] <- x
    m[Rfast::lower_tri(m)] <- Rfast::transpose(m)[Rfast::lower_tri(m)]
    m
}

vec2mat <- function(x){
    p <- sqrt(1 + 8 * length(x))/ 2 - 0.5
    m <- matrix(0, p, p)
    m[upper.tri(m, diag = TRUE)] <- x
    m[lower.tri(m)] <- t(m)[lower.tri(m)]
    m
}

y=numeric(500500)


> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(a<-vec2mat(y),b<-vec2mat_rfast(y),times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr     min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
         a <- vec2mat(y) 88.9461 101.5294 114.96752 108.86680 112.9854 180.9679    10
   b <- vec2mat_rfast(y) 33.1351  34.5294  49.61295  45.26955  62.8214  80.5069    10

> all.equal(a,b)
[1] TRUE
```